# Does Drupal supports multi-site management?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

Is multi-site management supported by Drupal? Whereas Drupal allows you to manage multiple sites from a single administrative interface. It means, for example, that you could run your main website, intranet, and satellite sites on the same Drupal instance, allowing you to maintain permission groups across the sites and a single point of login for your content producers.

Is this something that can be done with open source? Is it enterprise support from a hosting company like Acquia or Pantheon, for example?

Answer (score 2):

There is possibility to handle many drupal websites with the same codebase. You can use https://www.drupal.org/docs/multisite-drupal but it is kinda restricted. You pretty much use this when you want to make very simmilar or replica websites. For example a uni with different departments.

Answer (score 0):

You could build a Drupal website with [multi domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) and decide which content would go into which website. It can be complicated if different websites have great differences in matter of used modules and layout. But it will be working.

Some other solutions can be found Here

[A Complete Guide to Drupal SaaS Platforms](https://clientvenue.com/blog/drupal-saas/)